# Vuex state and vue-router

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to make a blog with vuejs and I'm a bit stuck. 
All my article data is in a Vuex Store like this :

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({    
state: {
    articles: [{
        title: "Article 1",
        id: 1,
        content:"Article 1 content"
    }, {   
        title: "Article 2",
        id: 2,
        content:"Article 2 content"
        }
    }]
}
```

I have a grid of articles on my homepage :

```
<div class="item-article" v-for="article in articles">
   <router-link :to="{path: '/article/'+article.id}"></router-link>
   <div>{{ article.title }}</div>
</div>
```

When I click on a grid article, I want it to redirect to the articlePage.vue component with the data of the same id article.

So far, on my articlePage.vue component I am with this :

```
<div v-for="article in selectedArticle">
   <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
   <p>{{ article.content }}</p>
</div>

computed: {
        selectedArticle(){
            return this.$store.state.articles.filter(article => article.id == this.$route.params.id);
        }
    }
```

I want to use `$route.params.id` in order to catch the matching id in VueX, and access to the the right data. But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: What does your router config look like? Are you seeing any error messages, or does the ID parameter not contain what you expect, or is the article data not showing, or is the component itself not loading, or what?  ("It's not working" is rarely enough information to go on; we need specifics.)

Comment: Yep sorry should have be more specific my bad! I have no error message, when I console.log(this.$store.state.articles) I have the array with all the data, which is ok! And the component itself si not loading

Comment: Even if it's not the "best" vue way (all the answers below are good answers, using vuex getters and props, using `find` instead of `filter` or using `name` and `params` for your `router-link`), your code actually works ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/2u3ph614/)). Maybe you just forgot the `router-view` ?

Comment: Wow I'm confused, I'm pretty sure it didn't work a few hours ago... I just tried again and it seems ok. Wizardry.

Answer (score 3):

First, define your routes and look how to create a dynamic route:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/articles/:id',
    name: 'articles',
    component: articlePage,
    props: true
  }
]
```

In your Vue instace, pass **routes** and **vuex store**:

```
new Vue({
  store,
  router: routes,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

In getters property in your Vuex Store, you need to create a method that filter/find article by id, something like that:

```
getArticlesById: (state) => (id) => state.articles.find(article => article.id === id)
```

And finally, in your mounted() method, call him:

```
this.article = this.$store.getters.getArticlesById(this.articleId)
```

**this.articleId** is the param sending by URL, remember define him in component props:

```
export default {
  name: "articlePage",
  props: ["category"],
...}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Name your routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html) and pass your **articleId** like this:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'article', params: { id: article.id }}">{{article.title}}</router-link>
```

Also, using [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/find) might be a better idea than using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/filter) because the second one would give you a one-element array in your case.

Comment: I tried with your way, but still no error, component not showing. I can see the array when I console.log(this.$store.state.articles) tho

Answer (score 1):

You should use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and add `return` within the find callback function

```js
selectedArticle() {

  let article = this.$store.state.articles.find(article => {

    return article.id == this.$route.params.id

  });

  return article;

}
```

Comment: Component doesn't load with no error, thank you anyway for your help!